# img align right not working html

Tags: html, image, alignment

I have this basic align code for an img i want to stay put in the top right corner of a page:

```
<a href= "main.html">
<img align="right"  
      position: relative; SRC="../img/vasi.jpg" width="100" height="100" ></a>
```

It has been working well but here it moves with the other code as well:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.newspaper {
-webkit-columns: 100px 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-columns:100px 4; /* Firefox */
columns: 100px 4;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
}

</style>
<STYLE>
</STYLE>
</head>
<body>
<a href= "main.html">
<img align="right"  
      position: relative; SRC="../img/vasi.jpg" width="100" height="100" ></a>
<div class="newspaper">
```

Hope someones understands and thanks!

Comment: You can add a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for front-end code.

Answer (score 1):

Bro just place your `<img>` within a `<div>`and give it a style as follows :

```
<div style="float:right;">
<img....................... >
</div>
```

This is it!!

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading more about html elements and their attributes. After getting a general information about it, go into styling with css.
What you asked for can be found below. i would advice to use the bootstrap framework to create a layout with colons, instead of the code you want to use.

```css
.newspaper {
-webkit-columns: 100px 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-columns:100px 4; /* Firefox */
columns: 100px 4;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href= "main.html">
<img align="right" style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;"src="../img/vasi.jpg" width="100" height="100" ></a>

<div class="newspaper">
<p>
paragraph1
</p>
<p>
another paragraph2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I'm self learned so sometimes I just get really confused ! And thanks for the tip about columns ;)

Comment: @GMM i can relate, im self learned too, but with experience things become easier. best of luck :D